# How do I flat a nested Json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe from a JSON, but I'm facing a problem with some nested data.

How can I take the information in the products columns and put then in other columns?

I'm currently doing this:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out



response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()


response = response['vendas']
response = pro
dic_flattened = [flatten_json(d) for d in response]
df_pandas = pd.json_normalize(dic_flattened)
df_pandas = pd.json_normalize(response)
dfa = dfa.append(df_pandas)
dfa
 

store_id | id   | products               |  payment
33       | 5    |[{'code': '17x555',     |  5
                  'lacre': '1578945a2',  |
```

Comment: Can you post an example of something you want flattened, and the expected output of doing so?

Comment: Are you looking to do `dfa = pandas.json_normalize(response)`?

Comment: @JonSG they did try that